# Should Association Bonus apply to the original site?

Tags: discussion, reputation

So I recently crossed the 200+ reputation threshold and got the association bonus (+100 rep for profiles on other sites) and the bonus was also applied to the site where I got the bonus. It seems odd to get a bonus +100 just for reaching 200 (it would make more sense to apply the bonus only to other associated sites where you don't have the 200+ reputation).

Is there a reason that the bonus applies to the original site where you already had a substantial reputation?

Comment: Incidentally, congratulations on reaching this milestone! SharePoint is one of the hardest sites in the network to earn rep on. I started here and in about 6 months I had earned around 125-150 rep. Then one day I answered a random question on another site, which earned me about 300 rep in one week.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the way this used to work is that when one profile crossed the 200 rep threshold, all other connected profiles would get the 100 rep bonus, but the one that had 200 rep wouldn't - except that if you had already also earned 100 reputation on your connected profile on another site, then that other profile will have crossed the 200 rep threshold, causing the first profile to get the association bonus as well.

Since I don't see that you've earned any rep on other sites, I can only conclude that they must have decided to simplify the process and just give you 100 rep everywhere from the get-go. The help center articles on reputation don't currently imply that the first profile to earn 200 rep doesn't itself receive the bonus, and I'm pretty sure they used to indicate this, so I believe things are working as intended.

Comment: I guess it makes sense in terms of simplification. I can see where there would be a lot of annoying instances in which a boost could trigger a second boost on another site. It just seems odd to grant rep for getting rep. Maybe they just accounted for the reputation gain in the amount required for privileges post 200 rep?